# Log4j: Log only message string without logging className and other details

Tags: log4j2

I have a java application and I am using log4j2. 
I want to only log the log message without logging things like className, log level, timestamp etc. 
I do see some suggestions regarding custom appender etc. But isn't there a simpler way to achieve this by just modifying the default configuration ?

Example:

```
log.info(" Hi This is a log message");
```

Desired Log statement

```
Hi This is a log message
```

Comment: show your log message and let me know the pattern you want

Comment: Thanks for replying. Edited with an example

Answer (score 2):

You have to change config file `log4j.xml`

The element need to be change in that file is  `pattern`  :
if you are using `log4j.properties` then change corresponding element.
example of pattern element:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d [%p] %c %m%n"/>
```

here **d** id for date
**p** is for priority
**c** is for Class Name 
**m** is fro message
**n** is fro separator
if you dont want any thing then remove from `pattern` entry.
Modified as per your requirement

```
<PatternLayout pattern=" %m%n"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Currently there is no log4j.xml file in the project. Shall i create one with just this one line in it -  <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%p] %c %m%n"/>?

Comment: yes add it in src folder & keep only  `**<PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>**`, before that check if the file **log4j.properties** exists

Comment: Thanks. And how can I do this only for a given class ? instead of whole project

Comment: yes, but youe need to add 1 more appender in config and specify the package like 
`log4j.logger.foo.bar.pacakge.Class=DEBUG, myappender`
`log4j.additivity.foo.pacakge.Class=false`

Comment: Sorry didn't get the last comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751399/log4j-writing-downsteams-logs-to-a-file